# How to redirect intended user to a different route based on their role?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to redirect my user to different route, based on their role. I have two secured area in my app, "admin" and "dashboard". I'd like to check if user is authenticated, then redirect to intended, but if user has role editor it should be redirected to dashboard, otherwise if he has role admin should be redirected to admin area.

I'm using AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers class in my login. I have this on my custom controller:

```
 /**
 * The default redirecTo path.
 *
 */
 protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

So when a user is authenticated it will be redirected to dashboard, but I'd like to check if the intended url is on admin group route and if user has admin role it should be redirected to admin area.

I'm using this middleware to redirect to login:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest())
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could overwrite the `redirectPath` method used by the trait in your `AuthController` to inject the logic you need. Something like this:

```
/**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    // Logic that determines where to send the user
    if (\Auth::user()->type == 'admin') {
        return '/admin';
    }

    return '/dashboard';
}
```

**EDIT:**

Laravel uses the following declaration in the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait to redirect the user after successful login:

```
return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

This will try to redirect the user to the previously attempted URL.

If you need to redirect users to the right place when they're already logged in, that would be best done by adding more logic to your authentication middleware.

Comment: This should work, but what if I want redirect to the full path? for example: user try to go to "admin/settings/general", is redirected to the login, he logs in and then is redirected to /admin, not the full path.

Comment: By default, Laravel will try to redirect to the intended URL first. If there wasn't one, it will fall back to this method.

Comment: I should set redirect url on the middleware?

Comment: You'll need to place the `redirectPath` method into your `AuthController` and modify the logic to your needs.

Comment: The problem here seems due to Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin*', array('admin'), Redirect::guest('auth/login') ); that not set correctly the intended url.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Entrust, so I don't know whether it captures the intended URL. Laravel 5 does for sure, however, so you might want to wrap your Entrust route rules in standard Laravel auth middleware first.

Answer (score 2):

> Another approach is to override `authenticated` method

```
public function authenticated()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin')) {
                return redirect('/admin-dashboard');
            } else {
                return redirect('/user-dashbaord');
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one. You also need to modify middleware **RedirectIfAuthenticated** so that it won't route home. Just to different user's dashboard.

```
public function authenticated()
{
    if($request->user()->hasRole('admin'))
             {
                 // return redirect()->intended(route('admin.index'));
                 return redirect()->route('admin.index');
             }
         if($request->user()->hasRole('super'))
             {
                 return redirect()->route('super.index');
             }
         if($request->user()->hasRole('officer'))
             {
                 return redirect()->route('officer.index');
             }   
}
```